# Iterate groovy map of maps with shell scripting

Tags: shell, groovy, pipeline

I have a groovy map which has an object(docker image) as the key and an array of values(docker tags for that docker object)

```
image_map = [obj_img_1: ['tag1','tag2'], obj_img_2: ['tag_x','tag_y']]
```

Now I want to iterate this groovy map where I can only get the tags as a shell script so I can do the following iteration

```
for image of images do
 for tag of tags do
   docker rmi $image:$tag
 done
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the map, iterate the tags:

```
image_map.each{ image, tags ->
    tags.each{ tag ->
        ["docker", "rmi", "${image}:${tag}"].execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I was able to do the expected task